# Does jquery sortable connected lists serialize only ever return the first list's order?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

If I'm using the connectWith property, I find that it only ever serializes the first ul list and not subsequent ones- which is obviously a deal breaker! Can anybody confirm this, and what I should do to serialize every list on update?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is yes. To extract each list, you must iterate over the connected list id's.